# How to add an origin point without adding anything else?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

How to add an origin point without adding anything else?
For example this could be done if you add a cube, go to edit mode , delete all vertice and you are left with an origin point but is there a faster way?

Comment: why do would want an origin point without vertices? Functionally in some cases, this would be an empty, so this might be an easier way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function is already delivered with Blender, just not enabled. Go to *File > User Preferences > Add-ons > Add Mesh* and enable *Add Mesh: Extra Objects*. Now if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in 3D View and go to *Mesh > Single Vert* you'll have an option called *Object Origin Only*. This will add an object origin in edit mode and you can start editing.